# ViewPager: define whether a fragment is selected/visible inside the fragment itself

Tags: android

Is there a way of defining whether a ViewPager's fragment is visible, active - the one a user sees - inside the fragment itself ?

I need to run my code(which is inside the fragment itself) specifically when the fragment is visible - not just adjacent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the status of the fragment at the specific instant.

Resumed:

The fragment is visible in the running activity.
Paused:
Another activity is in the foreground and has focus, but the activity in which this fragment lives is still visible (the foreground activity is partially transparent or doesn't cover the entire screen).
Stopped:
The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and member information is retained by the system). However, it is no longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is killed.

As referenced from: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: yeah, except that in ViewPager adjacent fragments are always in resumed state.